# Why doesn't scanf() take inputs from the user while dealing with strings?

Tags: c, input, scanf

My code is as follows

```
typedef struct
{
 char name[15];
 char country[10];
}place_t;  

int main()
 {
 int d;
 char c;
 place_t place;
 printf("\nEnter the place name : ");
 scanf("%s",place.name);
 printf("\nEnter the coutry name : ");
 scanf("%s",place.country);
 printf("\nEnter the type of the place : Metropolitan/Tourist (M/T)?");
 scanf("%c",&c);
 printf("You entered %c",c);
 return 0;
 }
```

If I run the program, it prompts for place name and country name, but never waits for the character input from user.
I tried

```
fflush(stdin);
fflush(stdout);
```

Neither work.

Note : Instead of a character, if I write a similar code to get an integer or a float, it prompts for values and the code works just fine.

```
int d;
printf("\nEnter the type of the place : Metropolitan/Tourist (M/T)?");
scanf("%d",&d);
```

Why does this happen? Is there anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf` leaves the whitespace following entered non-whitespace characters in the stream buffer, which is what the `scanf(%c...)` then reads. But wait a second...

In addition to being tricky to get right, such code using `scanf` is horribly unsafe. You're much better off using `fgets` and parsing the string later:

```
char buf[256];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
// .. now parse buf
```

`fgets` always gets a full line from the input, including the newline (assuming the buffer is large enough) and you thus avoid the problem you're having with `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string instead of character for scanf.

Answer (score 1):

```
 printf("\nEnter the place name : ");
 scanf("%s%*c",place.name);
 printf("\nEnter the coutry name : ");
 scanf("%s%*c",place.country);
 printf("\nEnter the type of the place : Metropolitan/Tourist (M/T)?");
 scanf("%c",&c);
 printf("You entered %c",c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding spaces before the ***%*** sign in scanf().
I have provided the modified code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    char name[15];
    char country[10];
} place_t;

int main()
{
    int d;
    char c;
    place_t place;
    printf("\nEnter the place name : ");
    scanf(" %s",place.name);
    printf("\nEnter the coutry name : ");
    scanf(" %s",place.country);
    printf("\nEnter the type of the place : Metropolitan/Tourist (M/T)?");
    scanf(" %c",&c);
    printf("You entered %c",c);
    return 0;
}
```