# Getting two characters in C

Tags: c, user-input, scanf

I'm trying to get two characters from the user. But i get an error. Let me explain it.

When i compile and run this code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

  int main(){
  char ch1,ch2;
  printf("Enter the first character: ");
  scanf("%c",&ch1);
  printf("Enter the second character: ");
  scanf("%c",&ch2);
  printf("The characters are %c and %c",ch1,ch2);
  return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
Enter the first character: 1
Enter the second character: The characters are 1 and
```

I can't enter the second character. But when i do this:

```
Enter the first character: 12
Enter the second character: The characters are 1 and 2
```

If i enter 12, the program make '1' the first character and make '2' the second character.

How can i get two characters from user without entering the two characters together.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C - fscanf in while loop skips user input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793909/c-fscanf-in-while-loop-skips-user-input)

Comment: "can't enter the second character." is incorrect. The first character was `'1'` and the 2nd character is the new-line or <Enter>.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%c` will eat up a character, whether it be a digit or whitespace. You probably want it to skip all whitespace and then eat up a character. You can do that by changing the format string from `%c` to  `%c`; that is, inserting a space before the `%c`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought it all day.